# MPI library and memory

Tags: c, memory, mpi

I have some problems with understanding how works shared memory. There are one main process and N others. The main process sent data to other, I made  it like this(data is placed in shared_mem[i] for i process):

```
int *shared_mem = calloc(numb_of_parts, sizeof(double));
if(world_rank == 0)
{
    for(int i = 1; i < numb_of_parts; i++)
    {
        MPI_Send(shared_mem+i, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
}
```

Next processes calculate something and write data in the same cell:

```
{
    MPI_Recv(shared_mem+world_rank, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    /* do smth with shared_mem[i] */
    MPI_Send(shared_mem+world_rank, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}
```

Then I wait for all processes and want to count the sum of all cells(with new data) in main process:

```
PI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
if(world_rank == 0)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < numb_of_parts; i++)
    {
        sum += shared_mem[i];
    }
}
```

But as a result I get always sum of previous data i.e. in main process array haven't changed. What is wrong?

Comment: 2 coments: 1/ `shared_mem` is a very bad name for for an array which isn't shared at all, and 2/ you declared it `int*` but used it as `double` so this will lead to problems...

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please already fix the data type issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try to decleare `double *shared_mem = calloc(numb_of_parts, sizeof(double));` ? For the moment, it is decleared as `int*`, so `shared_mem[i]` and `shared_mem+i` may not be what it is expected to be, since the size of `int` can be different from the size of `double`.

Moreover, there are features of `MPI` which can significantly help you:

- The function [`MPI_Scatter()`](http://mpitutorial.com/tutorials/mpi-scatter-gather-and-allgather/) and [`MPI_Reduce()`](http://mpitutorial.com/tutorials/mpi-reduce-and-allreduce/) using `MPI_SUM` can be combined.
- You can allocate shared memory between processes in a given communicator using [`MPI_Win_allocate_shared()`](http://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.2/www3/MPI_Win_allocate_shared.html), if such a thing is possible.

And @Gilles is right: the buffer `mem_shared` is not shared between processes. Indeed, each process allocates its own buffer `mem_shared` and this is the reason why message passing is required.

Here is a working code based on your code snippets. I had to add the receive par for the root process. Is it what is missing ? Compile with `mpicc main.c -o main -sdt=c99` and run it by `mpirun -np 4 main`.

```
/* -*- Mode: C; c-basic-offset:4 ; -*- */
/*
 *  (C) 2001 by Argonne National Laboratory.
 *      See COPYRIGHT in top-level directory.
 */

/* This is an interactive version of cpi */
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{

    int  numb_of_parts, rank;
    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&numb_of_parts);    


    int *mem = calloc(numb_of_parts, sizeof(double));
    if(rank == 0)
    {
        mem[0]=0;
        for(int i = 1; i < numb_of_parts; i++)
        {
            mem[i]=i;
            MPI_Send(mem+i, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);


        }
        for(int i = 1; i < numb_of_parts; i++)
        {
            MPI_Recv(mem+i, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
        }

    }else{
        MPI_Recv(mem+rank, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
        /* do smth with shared_mem[i] */
        mem[rank]=mem[rank]*2;
        MPI_Send(mem+rank, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }



    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    double sum=0;
    if(rank == 0)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < numb_of_parts; i++)
        {
            sum += mem[i];
        }

        printf("sum is %g\n",sum);
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

The problem can be in the `/* do smth with shared_mem[i] */`... if it does nothing, or if it does not modify `mem[rank]`.

Comment: I have fixed types, but still have same problem :(

Comment: Im so inattentive, I forget to recive message in main process, and ofc in main process nothing changes. Thank you!